# font-lock-fontify-keywords-region: Symbol's function definition is void: compilation--ensure-parse

Tags: ruby, emacs

I'm getting this error in Emacs when I attempt to run a spec test for any given Ruby file. My gem is set up in the standard way, with modules and classes in `lib/`, spec tests in `spec/`. My `.emacs` file has the following entries:

;; Ruby stuff

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/rvm.el")
(require 'rvm)
(autoload 'ruby-mode "ruby-mode"
  "Mode for editing ruby files" t)
(setq interpreter-mode-alist
      (append '(("ruby" . ruby-mode))
          interpreter-mode-alist))
(autoload 'run-ruby "inf-ruby"
  "Run an inferior Ruby process (irb)" t)
(autoload 'inf-ruby-keys "inf-ruby"
  "Set local key bindings for inf-ruby in ruby-mode")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rake$" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gemspec$" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rake$" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/[Rr]akefile$" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/Gemfile$" . ruby-mode))

(add-hook
 'ruby-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (rvm-activate-corresponding-ruby)
   (rspec-mode)))

(add-hook
 'ruby-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
    "bundle exec rake")
   (define-key ruby-mode-map "\C-c\C-b" 'compile) ; "Build and Test"
   )
 )


;; RSpec
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/rspec-mode")
(require 'rspec-mode)

;; Cucumber
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/feature-mode-0.4")
(require 'feature-mode)

;; Rinari
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/rinari")
(require 'rinari)

;; rails reloaded plugin
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/rails-reloaded")
(require 'rails-autoload)
```

Comment: I experience the same

Answer (score 2):

rspec-mode [uses compilation--ensure-parse on line 435](https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode/blob/24ee15006b14d25167553e3a1326ecb29c7d6ecd/rspec-mode.el#L435), in the `rspec-compilation-mode-font-lock-keywords` variable. The function `compilation--ensure-parse` was introduced in Emacs 24.1, so presumably rspec-mode is not guaranteed to work on earlier Emacs versions.